# How to get private key for the certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, private-key

Based on CSR I have got the certificate file (base64). now I need to convert this certificate to PEM format and I need a private key to import the certificate.

How do I create a private key from a certificate webserver.crt file using OpenSSL.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, you need to create a CSR on the server. by below command.

openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr

2. after generated CSR you will got mydomain.key mydomain.pem file.

Comment: Actually, I have created CSR in VMware vCenter 7 that doesn't have a key option during CSR creation process.